# Does $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(x^3) \, dx$ converge?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Does

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin (x^3) \, dx $$

converge? And If it does, why?

Comment: You may substitute $u=x^3$ (or equivalently, $x=u^{1/3}$). A more general discussion can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2275730/9340).

Comment: It does. I can't provide a real analysis driven proof, but I can provide a closed form for $I(n), \ n\gt 1$ which will be enough to decide whether the integral converges, or not. $$I(n) = \int_0^\infty \sin(x^n)\, \mathrm dx$$

Comment: An integration by part should probably help to show the convergence, like with the integral of sin(x^2) ?

Comment: Yes, Lelouch is right.  An integration by parts does this.  Personally, I would first substitute $y=x^3$ and then try to find an integration by parts to solve this.

Comment: I did it, but still didn't find a solution. Can you explain more please? @GEdgar

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155150/integrate-using-cauchy-integral-theorem

Comment: Apparent duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367333/how-to-prove-that-the-improper-integral-int-0-infty-sinx3-dx-converges?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

**not a solution**

Graphical evidence of convergence:
$$
\int_0^X \sin(x^3)\;dx
$$
[image: evidence]

---

Added: this is correct, verified by Wolfram Alpha:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+integral%28sin%28x%5E3%29%2Cx%3D0..X%29%3B+from+X%3D1+to+10